# How to read Image in POST request received using Jetty

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, jetty, afnetworking

I'm using a jetty server, and I have been trying to read the image which is appended as a form to the POST request I received. I've tried a few patterns but I always get exceptions.

```
//Process POST requests to upload images
private void handleImage(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

            //Get image
        byte[] pictureInByte = (request.getParameter("image")).getBytes();  
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureInByte);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

            //Save to disk
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpeg", new File(
                "new-darksouls.jpg"));



    }
```

This is how the POST is created (this is using Obj-C on an iPhone). I get the request on the Jetty server, but can't read it.

```
//Set http client defaults
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AS_NET_BASE_URL]];
        [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
        [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

        //init http request
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:route parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

            //Append data (JSON)
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:image
                                        name:@"image"
                                    fileName:@"2"
                                    mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }];

        //Time out
        [request setTimeoutInterval:AS_MI_NET_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];

        //Init operation
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

        //Set completion blocks
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            //Stop indicator
            [self stopNetworkIndicator];

            completion(YES, responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            [self stopNetworkIndicator];

            NSLog(@"%@", error);

            completion(NO, NULL);
        }];

        //Start spinning
        [self startNetworkIndicator];

        //Send request
        [operation start];

        //No internet, finish method
    }else{
        completion(NO, NULL);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AFMultipartFormData` class creates a [multipart request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

I don’t think Jetty supports the Servlet 3.0 spec yet (which would let you use `request.getParts()`), but you can use a 3rd party library (Spring/Apache commons) to parse the multipart request.

Searching on "apache commons fileupload multipart" should find some examples.

If you're using Spring, check out http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html

Comment: Also, the `Append data (JSON)` comment is wrong - that's not JSON :-)

Comment: Yeah, its adapted from my other method for json